# JSON validation against JSON schemas: Why is this obvious JSON data not failing validation

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

This JSON file should fail validation but it does not.  Someone tell me why.

Plug the below json data and schema into this web site, validate,
http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com
and I get the same results in the Mule Validate JSON Schema. Its obviously does not comply with the schema (i added some fields, I misspelled some fields, the date-time value is not a real date time) but yet it does not fail it.  Can someone tell me why?

JSON Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://hud.gov/ocio/xsd/esb/serviceauditingframework/2.0#",
  "definitions": {
    "serviceAuditLogData": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "serviceAuditLogData",
      "required": [
        "serviceRequestTimestamp",
        "sourceSystem"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "auditId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "serviceRequestTimestamp": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date-time"
        },
        "serviceProvider": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "serviceProviderVersion": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "serviceProviderTimestamp": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date-time"
        },
        "eventType": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "eventDetail": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "hostName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "sourceSystem": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "authenticationId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "endUserId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "inputData": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "propertiesOrder": [
        "auditId",
        "serviceRequestTimestamp",
        "serviceProvider",
        "serviceProviderVersion",
        "serviceProviderTimestamp",
        "eventType",
        "eventDetail",
        "hostName",
        "sourceSystem",
        "authenticationId",
        "endUserId",
        "inputData"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

JSON Data

```
   {
      "serviceAuditLogData": {
        "junk":"asdfasdf",
        "serviceRequestTimestamp": "2004-09-29T12:58:31.470Z",
        "serviceProvider": "FLQS",
        "serviceProviderVersion": "v1.0.1",
        "audit_id": "17f24136-2494-4bf8-9d3b-9baafaae0cc9",
        "serviceProviderTimestamp": "2012-11-04T21:44:57.997Z",
        "eventType": "Query Pool",
        "eventDetail": "default pool",
        "hostName": "esb-d-srv1.",
        "sourceSystem": "LRS",
        "authenticationId": "EsbLrsAccount",
        "endUserId": "H574857",
        "inputData": "L234234234, L32453462345, L23452346"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not fail because your schema does not enforce any constraint. Notice that `definitions` is not a `jsonschema` keyword that constraints validation. It is normally used to place sub-schemas that are re-used in other parts of the schema definition. Thus, to start with, you should change the `definitions` keyword for `properties`.

Another common misunderstanding with `jsonschema` is related to the `properties` keyword. Let's take the following example:

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "key1" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

You must read it as: `json` must be an object, and in the case that it contains a key equal to `key1`, its value must be a string. According to that the following two json objects are valid:

```
{
    "key2":12
}
```

And:

```
{
    "key1":"sdf"
}
```

Finally, related to `date-time` format, you must check the [section 6 of RFC3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) to be sure you have a valid date-time. And in any case, the implementation of formats is not compulsory in `jsonschema` validators.

Comment: Correction: `definitions` _is_ a schema keyword; however, its use is explicitly mentioned as a placeholder for subschemas to validate against in the current schema. Otherwise your interpretation is correct. Let's say that it is not a keyword which constrains validation :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jruizaranguren I also learned that I needed to place 
"additionalProperties": false, and "required": to make sure that whats' being passed in the API is what's expected.

The below is how I solved my problem.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "serviceAuditLogData": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "auditCorrelationId",
        "serviceRequestTimestamp",
        "serviceProvider",
        "serviceProviderVersion",
        "serviceProviderTimestamp",
        "eventType",
        "hostName",
        "sourceSystem",
        "authenticationId"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "auditCorrelationId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "serviceRequestTimestamp": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date-time"
        },
        "serviceProvider": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "serviceProviderVersion": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "serviceProviderTimestamp": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date-time"
        },
        "eventType": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "eventDetail": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "hostName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "sourceSystem": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "authenticationId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "endUserId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "inputData": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "serviceAuditLogData"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "serviceAuditLogData": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/serviceAuditLogData"
    }
  }
}
```